# Carousel indicator not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have made a carousel with 6 photos, but the carousel indicator below are not working. Only the first three carousel indicator, when clicked, take me to the correct slide (clicking 1st indicator takes me to first slide). Clicking the last three indicators results in no change in the carousel. Where am I going wrong?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slise-to="3"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slise-to="4"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slise-to="5"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slise-to="6"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <img src="nico-rosberg.jpg" class="cimg">
                                <img src="Taking%20control.png" class="cimg2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>Race info to go here</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <img src="nico-rosberg.jpg" class="cimg">
                                <img src="smile.png" class="cimg2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <img src="nico-rosberg.jpg" class="cimg">
                                <img src="question-mark.png" class="cimg2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <img src="nico-rosberg.jpg" class="cimg">
                                <img src="pulp%20fiction.jpg" class="cimg2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <img src="max.jpg" class="cimg">
                                <img src="look%20to%20your%20left.jpg" class="cimg2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <img src="lewis-hamilton.jpg" class="cimg">
                                <img src="le%20Ferrari.jpg" class="cimg2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: use `data-slide-to` instead of `data-slise-to`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <img src="nico-rosberg.jpg" class="cimg">
                            <img src="Taking%20control.png" class="cimg2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Race info to go here</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <img src="nico-rosberg.jpg" class="cimg">
                            <img src="smile.png" class="cimg2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <img src="nico-rosberg.jpg" class="cimg">
                            <img src="question-mark.png" class="cimg2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <img src="nico-rosberg.jpg" class="cimg">
                            <img src="pulp%20fiction.jpg" class="cimg2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <img src="max.jpg" class="cimg">
                            <img src="look%20to%20your%20left.jpg" class="cimg2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <img src="lewis-hamilton.jpg" class="cimg">
                            <img src="le%20Ferrari.jpg" class="cimg2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Oh gosh, that's embarrassing. I couldn't spot it! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Happens everyone everytime :-)